# .NET JSON: check structure

Tags: json, .net, json.net

I know I can check wether is a string is a valid JSON-formatted string using parsing functions and catching exceptions. But what I need is a bit more than that too.

I need to check if a string that comes in abides a certain model in JSON format.

E.g. I have this class

```
class MyClass {
  public String Key1 { get; set; }
  public List<MyClass2> Key2 { get set; }
  public int Key3 { get set; }
}

class MyClass2 {
  public int Key4 { get; set; }
}
```

and the following string `s1` comes in

```
{
  "Key1": "Hello",
  "Something": "World",
  "Key2": [
     { "Key4": 100 }
  ],
  "Key3": 2
}
```

Although `s1` IS a validly formatted JSON string, it does not abide by the structure of `MyClass1` since it has a property `Something` that is not a property of `MyClass1`. If however I receive the following string `s2`

```
{
  "Key1": "Hello",
  "Key2": [
     { "Key4": 100 }
  ]
}
```

then this would be valid for me even though there are properties missing. **Formally put, the given properties must be exactly a subset of the model's properties**.

How could I achieve this in .NET? Note that `MyClass` could be generic so I cannot hard check for names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) is a thing and, I would argue, should be used to validate JSON.

There are a number of different [implementations](https://json-schema.org/implementations) and a few of them are for .NET. There's even one from NewtonSoft - [JSON.Net Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) although [it's not completely free](https://www.newtonsoft.com/store/jsonschema)!

##### An example using [JsonSchema.Net](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything)

```cs
using Json.Schema;
using Json.Schema.Generation;
using Json.Schema.Serialization;

var json = @"{
  ""Key1"": ""Hello"",
  ""Something"": ""World"",
  ""Key2"": [
     { ""Key4"": 100 }
  ],
  ""Key3"": 2
}";

var schema = new JsonSchemaBuilder()
    .FromType<MyClass>()
    // Fail the validation if there any additional properties.
    .AdditionalProperties(JsonSchema.False)
    .Build();

var evaluationResults = schema.Evaluate(System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(json));

if (!evaluationResults.IsValid){
    // Log/throw an error here.
}
```

Comment: was about to suggest Newtonsoft JSON.Net Schema :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you could make a function to foreach on each property of your incoming object and if the whole object doesn't match your 'MyClass' return "False"

Kind Regards

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).